# Value of type 'ImageSlideshow?' has no member 'pageControlBottomPadding'

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode10.1, pagecontrol

When upgrade from swift3 to swift4, I have this error: Value of type `ImageSlideshow?` has no member `pageControlBottomPadding`

I use xcode10.1, swift4, target ios9.0 and above. `ImageSlideshow` version is 1.7.0.

There are also `warnings: 'pageControl' is deprecated: Use pageIndicator.view instead`

I think it might because the member name changed in swift4, the pageControl and its members are no longer used, and tried changing `pageControl` to `pageIndicator` or `pageIndicator.view`,

But I searched and cannot find the corresponding member name of  `currentPageIndicatorTintColor` and `pageIndicatorTintColor` and `pageControlBottomPadding`

Here's my code:

```
import ImageSlideshow
...
@IBOutlet weak var imageSliderView: ImageSlideshow!
...
imageSliderView.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = Color.Laser.instance()
        imageSliderView.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        imageSliderView.pageControlBottomPadding = 30.0
```

[image: screenshot image]

Any idea what new name should I use? Or is there a way I can still use "pageControl" in swift4? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pageControl` is deprecated in the latest version of ImageSlideshow.

[The example](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow/blob/master/Example/ImageSlideshow/ViewController.swift) from the library's github indicates that you should use `pageControl` like below. This will also get your deprecated warnings fixed:

```
@IBOutlet var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!

let pageControl = UIPageControl()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black

slideshow.pageIndicator = pageControl
```

To fix the error, use the following:

```
slideshow.pageIndicatorPosition = .init(horizontal: .center, vertical: .customBottom(padding: 30))
```

Comment: Thanks! The deprecate warning gone! But the error still exists. I tried the following method from here:https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow, which is:   slideshow.pageIndicatorPosition = PageIndicatorPosition(horizontal: .left(padding: 0), vertical: .bottom(padding: 30)), but get error: "Member 'bottom' takes no arguments

Comment: use `customBottom` instead of `bottom`